# Cannot install PySpatiaLite module ("SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print' ")

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, installation, python-module

When I run

```
 python3 -m pip install pyspatialite
```

I get the following error:

```
Collecting pyspatialite
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/2a/ffb126f3e8890ab0da951a83906e54528a13ce4b913303dea8bed904e160/pyspatialite-3.0.1-alpha-0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-14jnmfoo/pyspatialite/setup.py", line 66
        print "Is sphinx installed? If not, try 'sudo easy_install sphinx'."
                                                                           ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-14jnmfoo/pyspatialite/
```

I don't understand the issue. Is there a syntax error in the module PySpatiaLite? What do I do about it?

I am using Python 3.5 and Linux Bash Shell in Windows 10. If there is any additional info needed, let me know in the comments and I will edit the question.

Comment: Seems like this module is Python 2 only

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is a known issue in python 3:
https://github.com/lokkju/pyspatialite/issues/27

Answer (score 1):

```
print "Is sphinx installed? If not, try 'sudo easy_install sphinx'."
```

Seems that this library is written in Python 2.7 as they are using the Python 2 print statement. When pip3 runs the libraries setup.py the error you are receiving:

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Is entirely expected as the correct Python 3 syntax would be:

```
print("Is sphinx installed? If not, try 'sudo easy_install sphinx'.")
```

You can either switch to Python 2.7 for writing code to interface with this, or reach out to the contributors for assistance. Looking at their documentation on PyPi (https://pypi.org/project/pyspatialite/) it looks like the project is still in Alpha and has not been updated with a new release since 2013. I wouldn't expect much in terms of Python 3 compatibility without forking the source and correcting it yourself.

**EDIT**

Looking at the GitHub commits (https://github.com/lokkju/pyspatialite/commits/master) a small amount of commits have been merged in since 2013, but I would still not expect Python 3 support.